# How do breakpoints work when using a remote build host in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, embedded, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I have been tasked with setting up a development environment for an embedded platform. So far, I have set up a remote build host in NetBeans, which copies all of the source files to the target device, compiles them natively with the GNU toolchain on the device (`g++`, `ld`, etc.), and then runs the compiled binary and forwards stdout to the development machine that NetBeans is running on.

What I don't understand is: How does the binary on the build machine know where and when to start/stop if the breakpoints exist only in NetBeans? The build host only required ssh access and a compiling/linking toolchain, but somehow seems to communicate with NetBeans for debugging. A colleague of mine suggested it uses `gdbserver`, but I have not found any documentation on the NetBeans website about this package, and it is not installed on the build host (at least not from apt). How is NetBeans doing this?

Comment: gdbserver usually comes in with GCC. I'm not sure how your system's packaging is broken down. You may have to install a gdb package separately.  As for how to set it up in Netbeans... No clue.

Comment: @user4581301 `which gdbserver` doesn't return anything, so I don't think it is installed. Does `gdbserver` _have_ _to_ exist for this functionality to exist?

Comment: Probably, and it generally makes the job a hell of a lot easier even if there is a way around it. See if running `apt-get install gdb` on your target does anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI IDE's which use (or can be configured to use) a distinct command-line toolchain for compilation and debug typically do this by running each required toolchain program as a subprocess and interacting with it through standard streams.  Essentially, the IDE would use `gcc` or `gdb` with the same textual interface used when running it in a terminal window.  The IDE uses its knowledge of lines in the source file to configure breakpoints in `gdb` much as you would while running it by hand.

In your case, the IDE is configured to use a "remote host" for all of this, so instead of being invoked locally, the toolchain is controlled through as ssh session to the remote machine where both building and running occur.

Because the `gdb` debugger and the target program are running on the same computer, no `gdbserver` is required.

In the cases where `gdb` is too large for the target system, `gdbserver` is a small program which often gets cross-compiled for the target and loaded onto it.  This serves as a compact little delegate which talks to the main `gdb` program running on a build machine via a serial or network connection and performs the raw interaction with processor, memory, and running program on behalf of gdb.

Another possibility is that the `gdbserver` *role* is held by a helper program running on the same machine as `gdb` which instead commands something like a `JTAG debug adapter` to interact with the target hardware at a lower level.  In this case however, the helper program implementing the gdbserver protocol is not usually called "gdbserver" but instead has an implementation specific name, for example `openocd`.

Comment: In my scenario, machines 2 and 3 are the same machine. Ultimately, I would like machines 1 and 2 to be the same, but for the time being, I am currently compiling on the embedded platform. From your answer, I would assume that NetBeans is just issuing commands to the command-line version of `gdb` on the target platform over ssh and `gdbserver` is not involved. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  `gdbserver` would only be (sensibly) involved in the case where `gdb` is running on a different machine than the program being debugged.

Answer (score 0):

gdb runs on the target machine. Only communication with gdb (commands etc) goes via net to your local machine. Read gdb documentation if need to know more/

You can do exactly the same - just open the remote terminal , run gdbserver, start gdb and you are done :)

Comment: How is the target machine using `gdbserver` if it is not installed, though?

Comment: then that is a miracle.

Comment: @PeterJ `gdbserver` is only *required* when the program is running on a different computer than `gdb` is.  It's likely *possible* to run `gdb` and `gdbserver` on the same machine, but rather pointless to do so.

Comment: OP asked about **remote** debug. Anyway one of the best pieces of the debugging software (and hardware) - Segger J-Link uses gdbserver on the local machine and it is light speed fast comparing to another ones. Well written software, universal (local and remote), easy to configure - as it uses almost the same configuration for the local and remote debug

Comment: Remote in this case refers to the IDE<>GDB connection, not the GDB<>CPU one.  When GDB is not running on the target CPU, then yes, you can either talk a communication protocol to a gdbserver that is running on the target, or you can talk to something local like openocd that speaks the gdbserver protocol and controls the target via a hardware debug interface.  Segger is a bit unusual if they actually call their implementation of this gdbserver, but whatever.  It's all tangential to the question being asked here.  You generally don't use hardware debug for a program running under an OS.

Comment: It is even compiled remotely - so how can GDB access hardware on the remote machine.  `'So far, I have set up a remote build host in NetBeans, **which copies all of the source files to the target device**, compiles them natively with the GNU toolchain on the device (g++, ld, etc.), and then runs the compiled binary and forwards stdout to the development machine that NetBeans is running on.'`